# Is there any way to simplify $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if there is any way to express the sum $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}$ as only one binomial coefficient?

Comment: Pascal's identity: $$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$ but for the difference...

Comment: @DietrichBurde But this gives the difference only?

Comment: Yes, the sum need not be a nontrivial binomial coefficient, try easy examples.

Comment: Now... on the other hand, $\binom{k}{k}+\binom{k+1}{k}+\binom{k+2}{k}+\dots+\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}$ will simplify as per the hockey-stick identity to be $\binom{n+2}{k+1}$, but the identity you are hoping for is missing all of these leading terms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it isn't very enlightening: $$\binom{\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}}{1}$$ Unfortunately, there isn't a "nice" general way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Dietrich Burde, the answer will not (generally) be a single binomial coefficient.  But you can get it to be a single binomial coefficient times something:

$$\begin{array}{lll} {{n}\choose{k}}+{{n+1}\choose{k}} & = & \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+\frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!}\\ \\
&=&\frac{n!(n+1-k)+(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k1)!}\\ \\
&=& \frac{n!(2n+2-k)}{k!(n+1-k)!} \\ \\
&=& \frac{(n+1)!(2n+2-k)}{k!(n+1-k)!(n+1)}\\ \\
&=& {{n+1}\choose{k}}\frac{2n+2-k}{n+1}\\ \\
&=& {{n+1}\choose{k}}\left(2-\frac{k}{n+1} \right)
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

As **only one** binomial coefficient, I don't think so. We can take a simple example where $n =3$ and $k = 2$. Then $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2} = 3+6 = 9$, which can be written as $\binom{9}{1}$ and there is no other single binomial coefficient that gives $9$.